# Deleting empty rows in a 3D cell array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, cell-array

I have a large **3D** CELL ARRAY (x1) which I have to delete the empty rows.
How can I do this?

Example of my cell array (some pieces of the variable):

```
val(:,:,1) = 

[20]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
[ 0]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
[ 0]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
[]      []    []    []    []    []    []    []

(...)

val(:,:,42) = 


[ 34225]    [   215]    [    0]    [   0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]
[ 85200]    [   545]    [    0]    [   0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]
[ 65074]    [   190]    [ 1000]    [   0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]
[ 81570]    [  1385]    [ 2475]    [   0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]    
[ 67236]    [   530]    [  365]    [   0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]
[ 61338]    [     0]    [  100]    [   0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]    [    0]
[]          []          []         []        []         []         []         []    
[]          []          []         []        []         []         []         []  
[]          []          []         []        []         []         []         []
```

In this case, I want to exclude the 4th row of `(:,:,1)`, the three last rows from `(:,:,42)` and all the others from these variable.

I've tried

```
x1(all(all(cellfun((@isempty,x1),2),:,:) = [];
```

But it gave me this following error:

Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly
unbalanced (, {, or [.

PS: I cannot use `"=="` because its a cell array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, counting the parentheses, you have 5x `(` and only 3x `)` ...

Comment: making parentheses correct doesn't solve the error it seems

Comment: Please post what you get once you've corrected the problem with the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks! Going to test and answer this

Comment: I've tested this possibilities:
    `x1(all(all(cellfun((@isempty,x1),2),:,:))) = [];`

    `x1(all(all(cellfun((@isempty,x1),2),:),:)) = [];`

    `x1(all(all(cellfun((@isempty,x1),2)),:,:)) = [];`

    `x1(all(all(cellfun((@isempty,x1),2)),:),:) = [];`
And all of those gave me the same error as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two problems here.  One is the fact that you are using a 3D cell array, and it appears that you want to delete different numbers of rows from different planes.  This would give you something that does not form a proper MxNxP structure, because M won't be the same.

That said, I can tell you how to remove the rows that are all empty in a 2D cell array.  Let's say `val` is MxN.  Then

```
val2 = val(~all(cellfun(@numel,val)==0,2),:);
```

If you want to work with the 3D data you described, you'll have to store the result for each plane separately in a cell.  Something like this:

```
val2 = cell(1,1,size(val,3));
for i = 1:size(val,3)
    valplane = val(:,:,i);
    val2{i} = valplane(~all(cellfun(@numel,valplane)==0,2),:);
end
```

Comment: Also, since each cell in `val` contains only one number, I suggest storing the final result as a cell array of matrices rather than a cell array of cells. Therefore, I'd do `valplane = cell2mat(val(:, :, i));`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm testing it right now (@nhowe)
Eitan T, thanks, but in some parts of the cell I have dates too

Comment: @@nhowe I tested it and it gave me:
 x2{i} = valplane(~all(cellfun(@numel,x1)==0,2),:);
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: Sorry, original post had a typo, which I have now fixed.  You want `x2{i} = valplane(~all(cellfun(@numel,valplane)==0,2),:);`

Comment: I'm VERY VERY VERY grateful !
It worked perfectly!
You are awesome dude, smart code!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you for a particular row, say the first row:

```
i=1;    %Row number
val(~all(cellfun(@isempty,val(:,:,i)')),:,i);
```

For example:

```
>> 
val = cell(4,8,2);
val(:,:,1) = {
[20]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
[ 0]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
[ 0]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
[]      []    []    []    []    []    []    []
};
>> 
i=1;    %Row number
val(~all(cellfun(@isempty,val(:,:,i)')),:,i)
```

The result was:

```
ans = 

    [20]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    [ 0]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    [ 0]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to do this without doing for each dimension!

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** remove different rows from a 3D array, you can remove 'floors', or layers or 'walls'. (If you imagine a building by layer I intend a vertical and perpendicular plane to your point of vision while a wall is a vertical plane along your point of vision).

You **should not** store numeric data in this way, i.e. one number per cell. 
You incur in a 112 bytes **overhead** per cell when a scalar double is only 8 bytes.

According to the sparsity pattern I can observe from your example, you might benefit by converting it into a **sparse** array which still reference against the original size of the array but without storing `0` or `[]`. However, sparse arrays are only 2D, where the additional layers (from a 3rd dimension) are stored consecutively along the 2nd dimension.

A simplified version of your example will clarify:

```
val(:,:,1) = {
[20]    []    []    []
[ 0]    []    []    []
[ 0]    []    []    []
[]      []    []    []};
val(:,:,2) = {
[ 34225]    [   215]    [    0]    [   0]    
[ 85200]    [   545]    [    0]    [   0]   
[ 65074]    [   190]    [ 1000]    [   0]   
[]          []          []         []     };

% Find non-zero empty elements (0s will be discarded automatically)
[r,c] = find(~cellfun('isempty',val));

% Convert to sparse (note the coordinates are only 2D)
sp    = sparse(r,c,[val{:}]);
sp =
   (1,1)             20
   (1,5)          34225
   (2,5)          85200
   (3,5)          65074
   (1,6)            215
   (2,6)            545
   (3,6)            190
   (3,7)           1000

% Convert to full to see what happened with the 3rd dimension
full(sp)
ans =
     20      0      0      0  34225   215     0     0     
      0      0      0      0  65074   190     0     0
      0      0      0      0  85200   545  1000     0
```

you can see that the second layer has been concatenated horizontally (along columns). You can use reshape if you need to recover the 3D.

The advantage of `val` vs `sp` is in the reduced storage:

```
  Name      Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes
  sp        3x8                200  double    sparse    
  val       4x4x2             3704  cell
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, it was a very different solution. Nevertheless, in my cell I have some dates, not only numeric data. 
Also, I need my ZEROS, because they are valuable information too. 
I dont need the FULLY EMPTY ROWS, only.

But thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: Dates can be stored as serial numbers, and I recommend to do that with `datenum()`. Good remark about the zeros.